# RPS multiple responses on discord

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So, i tried making a rock, paper, scissors command on my discord bot.
The way this code works is that a user reacts to one of the emojis which is his/her choice and the bot randomly chooses its response and sends it.
Here's the code:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'rps-game',
    description: 'play a rps game',
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client) {
        const rockemoji = ''
        const paperemoji = ''
        const scissorsemoji = '✂'

        const rpsembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('A game of RPS')
            .setDescription('React to one of the emojis below!')

        const messageEmbed = await message.channel.send(rpsembed)

        messageEmbed.react(rockemoji)
        messageEmbed.react(paperemoji)
        messageEmbed.react(scissorsemoji)

        client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch()
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch()
            if (user.bot) return
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return

            const rpschoices = ['', '', '✂']
            const unexchoice = rpschoices[Math.floor(Math.random() * rpschoices.length)]

            if (reaction.emoji.name === rockemoji && unexchoice === "") {
                const unexwin1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle('RPS results')
                    .addFields(
                        { name: 'Your Choice', value: '' },
                        { name: 'Unex\'s Choice', value: '' }
                    )
                message.channel.send(unexwin1)
                message.channel.send('Unex wins!')
                return
            }
            else if (reaction.emoji.name === paperemoji && unexchoice === "✂") {
                const unexwin2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle('RPS results')
                    .addFields(
                        { name: 'Your Choice', value: '' },
                        { name: 'Unex\'s Choice', value: '✂' }
                    )
                message.channel.send(unexwin2)
                message.channel.send('Unex wins!')
                return
            }
            else if (reaction.emoji.name === scissorsemoji && unexchoice === "") {
                const unexwin3 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle('RPS results')
                    .addFields(
                        { name: 'Your Choice', value: '✂' },
                        { name: 'Unex\'s Choice', value: '' }
                    )
                message.channel.send(unexwin3)
                message.channel.send('Unex wins!')
                return
            }
            else if (reaction.emoji.name === rockemoji && unexchoice === "") {
                const unextie1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle('RPS results')
                    .addFields(
                        { name: 'Your Choice', value: '' },
                        { name: 'Unex\'s Choice', value: '' }
                    )
                message.channel.send(unextie1)
                message.channel.send('Its a tie!')
                return
            }

            else if (reaction.emoji.name === paperemoji && unexchoice === "") {
                const unextie2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle('RPS results')
                    .addFields(
                        { name: 'Your Choice', value: '' },
                        { name: 'Unex\'s Choice', value: '' }
                    )
                message.channel.send(unextie2)
                message.channel.send('Its a tie!')
                return
            }
            else if (reaction.emoji.name === scissorsemoji && unexchoice === "✂") {
                const unextie3 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle('RPS results')
                    .addFields(
                        { name: 'Your Choice', value: '✂' },
                        { name: 'Unex\'s Choice', value: '✂' }
                    )
                message.channel.send(unextie3)
                message.channel.send('Its a tie!')
                return
            }
            else if (reaction.emoji.name === rockemoji && unexchoice === "✂") {
                const userwin1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle('RPS results')
                    .addFields(
                        { name: 'Your Choice', value: '' },
                        { name: 'Unex\'s Choice', value: '✂' }
                    )
                message.channel.send(userwin1)
                message.channel.send('You win!')
                return
            }
            else if (reaction.emoji.name === paperemoji && unexchoice === "") {
                const userwin2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle('RPS results')
                    .addFields(
                        { name: 'Your Choice', value: '' },
                        { name: 'Unex\'s Choice', value: '' }
                    )
                message.channel.send(userwin2)
                message.channel.send('You win!')
                return
            }
            else if (reaction.emoji.name === scissorsemoji && unexchoice === "") {
                const userwin1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle('RPS results')
                    .addFields(
                        { name: 'Your Choice', value: '✂' },
                        { name: 'Unex\'s Choice', value: '' }
                    )
                message.channel.send(userwin1)
                message.channel.send('You win!')
                return
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The problem:
on the first use, the bot returns one message, on the second use, the bot returns two messages and so on

As you can see, i have already tried return but it wont wont work.

Comment: That's because you set up an event listener (aka `client`) inside your code that gets added every time you use the command but you don't tell it to stop after every time. This means that once you tell it for another round, there'll be an additional listener.

Comment: So in the first round you'll get 1 event listener. Second time, you'll trigger yet another listener without turning the previous one off, and so on. I'd suggest you check out [`awaitReactions`](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#await-reactions) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because you added the `messageReactionAdd` event listener in your command. Every time that you command is called, another event listener is created and will execute the code another time. Instead of putting the event listener within your command, you could use [`awaitReactions`](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#await-reactions). These will allow you to check for reactions on your message for a certain amount of time after they were sent. For example:

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    const rpschoices = ['', '', '✂']
    return rpschoises.includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
};
messageEmbed.awaitReactions(filter, { /*options*/ })
    .then(collected => {}) //your handler code here
```

You can read more about the options and methods of awaitReactions in [the docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=awaitReactions).

Comment: thnx for the help !

Comment: btw do i have to put the possibilities in the your handler code section?